# On scroll the active menu does not chaning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a right side menu but when i scrolling down it is not changing the active class to next menu,I've used this code lots of time but this time i'm not getting the result,

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

    scrollLink.each(function() {

      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 70;

      if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
       $('.icons').removeClass('iconactive');
       $(this).children('.icons').addClass('iconactive'); 

      }
    });
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4t7kfjeq/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define scrollLink and you can give some animation effect when you click an anchor link by adding a function like this

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
     }, 1000);
 });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3xmop98u/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `var scrollLink = $('.myanimate');` in your code. Adding this line in your DEMO make the code work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
    var scrollLink = $('.myanimate');
    scrollLink.each(function() {

      var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 70;

      if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
       $('.icons').removeClass('iconactive');
       $(this).children('.icons').addClass('iconactive'); 

      }
    });
  });

  $(".myanimate").click(function (){
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 2000);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much but when ic lcik on the right rounded menu it is jumping to that section not giving any scroll effect